# How do I patch this wall?

Tags: bathroom, patching-drywall

I tried to hang an adhesive towel rack (it was up for about 30 seconds) and I took it off to readjust it and a chunk of the wall came off. How do I patch it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove any loose debris and use some [fast drying spackling](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-Fast-Dry-32-fl-oz-Heavy-Duty-Waterproof-Interior-Exterior-White-Spackling/1002653466?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-1002653466-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiArrCvBhCNARIsAOkAGcUtgPPpT1CQcQ19FnZSD5fxKr9A3bJxZOm3IIkn_adfTPlMJof4MkYaAkdSEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). Sand when dry and paint.

I avoid stick on towel racks. Try to find those that require screws and anchor plates.

Comment: It looks like concrete behind that.  For a simple towel bar, might be too much work or a good reason to go to the toy store for a hammer drill and masonry bits/anchors

Comment: Fast drying will not help here !